# Underscore.js Find and return element using nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have data-structure like this

```
        var masterObj = [{
            "_id" : "2i4NGzpEpnKZhkxY8",
            "master_sku" : "UAT43-S",
            "available" : [ 
                {
                    "marketplace_name" : "xyx",
                    "doc_id" : "WCw8Hsyw4D3ab8TAZ"
                }
            ]
        }
        {
            "_id" : "2mf6hghQ7f32CrA3X",
            "master_sku" : "UAT43-XL",
            "available" : [ 
                {
                    "marketplace_name" : "abc",
                    "doc_id" : "QduDKpT2HqmuaFHRz",
                }
            ]
        }]
```

I am using underscor.js and my Query is like this

```
  var result = _.findWhere(masterObj, { "available.doc_id": "WCw8Hsyw4D3ab8TAZ" });
```

Required result is

```
   {
        "_id" : "2i4NGzpEpnKZhkxY8",
        "master_sku" : "UAT43-S",
        "available" : [ 
            {
                "marketplace_name" : "xyx",
                "doc_id" : "WCw8Hsyw4D3ab8TAZ"
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can i get desigred output. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need underscore for this. Use JavaScript's native [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) array method with a callback function to find an element `available` array that has the correct `doc_id`.

If you know that `available` will only have one element:

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"2i4NGzpEpnKZhkxY8","master_sku":"UAT43-S","available":[{"marketplace_name":"xyx","doc_id":"WCw8Hsyw4D3ab8TAZ"}]},{"_id":"2mf6hghQ7f32CrA3X","master_sku":"UAT43-XL","available":[{"marketplace_name":"abc","doc_id":"QduDKpT2HqmuaFHRz"}]}]

const result = arr.find(obj => {
  return obj.available[0].doc_id === 'WCw8Hsyw4D3ab8TAZ';
});

console.log(result);
```

If `available` has more than one element use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const arr = [{"_id":"2i4NGzpEpnKZhkxY8","master_sku":"UAT43-S","available":[{"marketplace_name":"xyx","doc_id":"WCw8Hsyw4D3ab8TAZ"},{"marketplace_name":"bob","doc_id":"WCw8Hsyw4D3a8TAZ"}]},{"_id":"2mf6hghQ7f32CrA3X","master_sku":"UAT43-XL","available":[{"marketplace_name":"abc","doc_id":"QduDKpT2HqmuaFHRz"}]}]

const result = arr.find(obj => {
  return obj.available.some(el => el.doc_id === 'WCw8Hsyw4D3ab8TAZ');
});

console.log(result);
```